# Pandas Create a data frame from a loop

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe, list, function

I would like to ask you how I could build a dataframe inside a loop
starting from the values of a column.
The initial dataframe is:

```
data = {'Name': ['Computer','Tablet','Monitor','Printer'],
         'Price': [900,300,450,150],
         'Identifier': ['11$10qw-IDAA','2222-IL$DB123-ABC','33-$IDCCC-12345', '1as3211-223$eww3']
         }
```

First I would like to split the "Identifier" column based on the '-' character.
Secondly, I would like to create a dataframe made up of columns:

- Name of the df dataframe
- String_02 as part of the "Identifier" string.

example:

```
Name        Stringa_02
Computer    11$10qw
Computer        IDAA 
Tablet      2222
Tablet      IL$DB123
Tablet      ABC
```

Thank you and hello to everyone

Comment: `df.assign(Identifier=df['Identifier'].str.split('-')).explode('Identifier')`